# What is the latest version of opensaml?

Tags: java, opensaml

Regarding the heading, can someone tell me what is the latest version of opensaml-saml-api?

I can see that on maven repository(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/opensaml/opensaml-saml-api/) it's latest version is listed as `4.0.1`

Is there any other official site where I can get hold of latest opensaml version information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation you're referring to is the one developed by Shibboleth and yes their latest version is the 4.0.1. On their website they strongly encourage switching to their latest version or other alternatives as every V2 security update ceased in 2016 for Java and 2018 for C++.

> As of July 31, 2016, all security maintenance for the OpenSAML V2 Java release branch ceased. A complete schedule of the dates can be found here. All deployments should upgrade to V3 or evaluate other alternatives.

> As of July 17th, 2018, all security maintenance for the OpenSAML V2 C++ release branch ceased. The author encourages anybody using that code to seek other options or, preferably, stop implementing SAML yourself and use an existing implementation. There are no plans to ever provide meaningful documentation or support for any use of that code outside the Shibboleth Project. Use it at your own risk.

However, there are many other implementations that you can find linked on their [website](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenSAML/overview)

[On maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-saml-impl/4.0.1/jar), you can check every version of Shibboleth's implementation from V3 to their latest one (the 4.0.1).

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, there are newer releases, up to 4.3.0 as of July 2023: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.opensaml/opensaml-core?repo=shibboleth-releases

However, 4.0.1 is still the latest version on Maven Central. The newer versions are only available from Shibboleth's own repository.

Comment: Followed by 5.0.0 Sept 23 (https://build.shibboleth.net/maven/releases/org/opensaml/opensaml-parent/5.0.0/)